# Replacing specific text in PowerPoint using office.js and add-in

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js

I have a requirement where I need to replace some text in a Powerpoint File at runtime.

In word I can get range object and replace text, like this:

```
var results = ctx.document.body.search("TEXT TO SEARCH", {
  matchCase: true,
  matchWholeWord: wholeWord
});

ctx.load(results);

return ctx
  .sync()
  .then(function () {
    for (var j = 0; j < results.items.length; j++) {
      var range = results.items[j];
      ctx.load(range);

      range.select();
      range.insertHtml("NEW TEXT", "replace");
    }
  })
```

but I can't find anything similar in Power Point API. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I'm afraid this type of interaction isn't supported by PowerPoint. PPT supports a _very_ limited set of APIs.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur As I thought, thanks for your reply